# Documents on a rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-design

I am developing a portal of sorts in Ruby on Rails using PostgreSQL.
I require different pages (each page represents a different topic of interest) on the portal to show different documents. The admin will have the ability to upload additional documents to each page. 
No where is the entire list of documents on the website ***required***

What is the best practice to implement such a system and is there any tutorials for the same?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a content management system. [Alchemy CMS](https://alchemy-cms.com/about) is a good choice for rails.

Answer (score 0):

That's a *multi-tenant* application, and normally you do this by associating all the records with a user or an account, sometimes both. This is done with a `has_many`/`belongs_to` pair most of the time for any records that are user or account specific.

You'll also have to be specific in each controller to only access records that the person can see, so you'll need to define an access control mechanism of some kind. [There's modules for this](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), writing your own can be tricky.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. The different pages do not reflect different users, but just different parts of the portal. For example, documentation documents on the documentation page, 'life tips' on the lifestyle page etc.

In terms of a separate question, I am also trying to figure out how to give users different privileges (i.e. admin and end users) and I think this helps a little there

Comment: If you're still hazy on how this is done it's worth looking at existing [CMS platforms](https://hackhands.com/9-best-ruby-rails-content-management-systems-cms/) for Rails.